# importance of __clang_analyzer__

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

What is the importance of **clang_analyzer** as without using this I see analyzer shouting a leak on the below piece of code.

```
#ifndef __clang_analyzer__
CGPathRef pathWithRoundRect(CGRect iRect, CGFloat iRadius) {
    CGMutablePathRef returnVal = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint();
    CGPathAddArcToPoint();
    CGPathAddArcToPoint();
    CGPathAddArcToPoint();
    CGPathAddArcToPoint();
    CGPathCloseSubpath(returnVal);
    return returnVal;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Well you are leaking returnVal... I'm guessing that with that #ifndef, that code is not compiled and therefore doesn't tell you about the leaks in it.

Comment: @Emilio: It's not a leak; the caller of the function still has a reference to the `CGPath`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__clang_analyzer__` is a macro, defined when the program is compiled for the analyzer (see the [Clang User's Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#analyzer_diagnositics)).

When it's defined, the code between `#ifndef` and `#endif` isn't being compiled, which means that the analyzer doesn't see it and can't tell you about the owned `CGMutablePath` that you're returning from a function whose name doesn't indicate it returns an owning reference.

You should consider adding `create` to the beginning of the function name.

Comment: So that means 'returnVal' is always leaking? How to stop this?

Comment: It's not leaking -- you still have a reference to it when the function returns. It's just that the caller owns it and is responsible for releasing it when done.

Comment: @Abhinav also take a look at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.c-retainable